# Particle 'energy' can not be set anymore

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the following scripts and I can not convert to new unity classes. This script written 6-7 years ago and now it can not be used.

It throws an errors about `Particle[]` class because it is now '`ParticleSystem.Particle[]`'

I am just designer, can not convert this lines to new system. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LightningBolt : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public int zigs = 100;
    public float speed = 1f;
    public float scale = 1f;
    public Light startLight;
    public Light endLight;

    Perlin noise;
    float oneOverZigs;

    private Particle[] particles;

    void Start()
    {
        oneOverZigs = 1f / (float)zigs;
        particleEmitter.emit = false;

        particleEmitter.Emit(zigs);
        particles = particleEmitter.particles;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if (noise == null)
            noise = new Perlin();

        float timex = Time.time * speed * 0.1365143f;
        float timey = Time.time * speed * 1.21688f;
        float timez = Time.time * speed * 2.5564f;

        for (int i=0; i < particles.Length; i++)
        {
            Vector3 position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, target.position, oneOverZigs * (float)i);
            Vector3 offset = new Vector3(noise.Noise(timex + position.x, timex + position.y, timex + position.z),
                                        noise.Noise(timey + position.x, timey + position.y, timey + position.z),
                                        noise.Noise(timez + position.x, timez + position.y, timez + position.z));
            position += (offset * scale * ((float)i * oneOverZigs));

            particles[i].position = position;
            particles[i].color = Color.white;
            particles[i].energy = 1f;
        }

        particleEmitter.particles = particles;

        if (particleEmitter.particleCount >= 2)
        {
            if (startLight)
                startLight.transform.position = particles[0].position;
            if (endLight)
                endLight.transform.position = particles[particles.Length - 1].position;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
particles[i].energy = 1f;
```

with

```
particles[i].remainingLifetime = 1f;
```